# is the window global object reassignable?

Tags: javascript

As simple as this:

```js
window = 'Hello world';
console.log(window);
```

I am pretty sure this should work and post in console 'Hello world', but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

No. In sloppy mode, it'll fail silently. In strict mode, you'll see an explicit error.

```js
'use strict';
window = 'Hello world';
console.log(window);
```

You can't reassign it. I think the best you could do is to create a *new* variable named `window` not on the top level.

```js
(() => {
  const window = 'Hello world';
  console.log(window);
})();
```